# make the text justified "text-align:justify" in telerik

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I get the PDF output using Telerik.  I want to justify the text.

```
c# 
"<p style='text-align:center;'>" + result + "</p>"   -->work
"<p style='text-align:left; '>" + result + "</p>"   -->work
"<p style='text-align:right;'>" + result + "</p>"   -->work

"<p style='text-align:justify;'>" + result + "</p>"   --> don't work
```

> centered text in pdf file.

```
<p style='text-align:center;'>" + result + "</p>"   -->work
```

[image]

> telerik settings:
>   telerik do not support text-justify. I have to justify the text, how
>   do I do it?
>   http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radrichtextbox/import-export/features-html-support
>   http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/report-items-html-text-box.html

[image]

Comment: in the latest release [Telerik Reporting Q1 2015](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/report-items-html-text-box.html) it said that _text-align:justify_ is supported. when i try it, it still doesnt work. Huh!

Answer (score 1):

```
var cTyp = dt.Columns[i].DataType.ToString();
            if (cTyp == "System.Decimal")
            {
                textboxGroup.Style.TextAlign = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.HorizontalAlign.Right;
                textBoxTable.Style.TextAlign = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.HorizontalAlign.Right;

            }
```